# Why is the median filter called 'edge-preserving'?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, median-filter, edge-preserving-filter

I want to know about median filtering. Recently, I read that it is best for preserving edges. But how does it preserve edges?

I need complete knowledge of median filters. Why it is non-linear filter and why it is best, compared to linear filter?

Comment: try to delete it .but can't delete.

Comment: hey sufi, you might want to look at [this other answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36348/how-to-build-a-median-filter-function).

Answer (score 7):

**Non-linearity**

A linear filter is mathematically described by the convolution sum (for discrete signals) and the convolution integral for continuous signals. The median cannot be found using a linear function except in the trivial case where you have a discrete filter of size 1, which is why the median filter is non-linear.

**Edge Preserving Properties.**

> Median filtering is one kind of smoothing technique, as is linear
>   Gaussian filtering. All smoothing techniques are effective at removing
>   noise in smooth patches or smooth regions of a signal, but adversely
>   affect edges. Often though, at the same time as reducing the noise in
>   a signal, it is important to preserve the edges. Edges are of critical
>   importance to the visual appearance of images, for example. For small
>   to moderate levels of (Gaussian) noise, the median filter is
>   demonstrably better than Gaussian blur at removing noise whilst
>   preserving edges for a given, fixed window size. However, its
>   performance is not that much better than Gaussian blur for high levels
>   of noise, whereas, for speckle noise and salt and pepper noise
>   (impulsive noise), it is particularly effective. Because of this,
>   median filtering is very widely used in digital image processing.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter#Edge_preservation_properties)

Comment: i want to how it preserve edge since edge and noise both have high frequency. ?

Comment: It's not really useful to think of the spectral properties when performing non-linear filtering since non-linear filters by definition don't have a transfer function (which is based on the convolution sum). Median filtering can be thought of as a "despiker" function. I found https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1d86/419106054215ddd43f90e0c01a388527ec76.pdf which describes this in more detail. While the term "low-pass" median filter is often used, its really a misnomer because median filters don't pass only low frequencies.

Comment: i wonder how many pixels wide is a median filter used that preserves the edges?

Answer (score 4):

A median filter changes the value of one given pixel by the median value (or a weighted version) of a patch of pixels (most often around the given pixel). Generally, the patch contains an odd number of pixels: $\pm K$ above and below, left and right, with a total of $(2K+1)^2$.

I will details three basic scenarios:

- clean edge (1D vision): suppose that the image is all black on the left ($0$ value), white on the right  ($255$ value), a clear vertical edge. If you take a line, across the edge, the values will be $(\ldots,0,0,0,255,255,255\ldots)$. A 3-point median does a perfect job: the patch $(0,0,255)$ yields $0$, the patch $(0,255,255)$ yields $255$. Now look across columns: they are constant, so the output of a  A 3-point median yelds the same constant. This also works with any $2m+1\times 2n+1$ patch. So the clean edge is fully preserved, while a linear filter (non-trivial) would average values, and yields non integer pixels, introducing additional rounding errors
- pure flat+gaussian noise: the median is a robust estimator of the flat value, and can reduce the variance of the noise (I can add references if needed)
- pure flat (or pure noise)+ isolated outliers: depending on the number of outliers and the size of patch, the outliers are strongly shrunk toward the flat or a noise value.

It is non-linear, since the median of $(0,1,2)$ is $1$, the median of $(3,1,1)$  is $1$, but the median of $(0,1,2)+(3,1,1)$ is $3$, and not $1+1$.

So it can be better than linear filters, but this depends on the nature of edges, noise properties and patch size. Others sources on SE.DSP:

- [What is the advantage of weighted median filter over median filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25850/15892)
- [What is the math behind median filter's noise reduction property?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15203/what-is-the-math-behind-median-filters-noise-reduction-property)